# What is the difference in the input from inbuilt microphone and an external microphone amplifier?

Tags: arduino, noise, matlab

I wrote a MATLAB script interfacing my laptop's inbuilt microphone to calculate the dbA levels of noise in my classroom. (un-calibrated, as of now)

I want to now use this dbA calculation script on data from my arduino. (Electret Microphone Amplifier 4466). 
I want know what is the difference in the 2 inputs and what changes I should make in acquiring my data from the arduino to receive the same result as I did with the inbuilt microphone.

Answer (score 1):

Without precise data from the laptop manufacturer the best procedure may be:

- Get a tone generator app for your phone.
- Play a 1 kHz tone on a loudspeaker.
- Position both measuring systems equidistant from the sound source.
- Perform some measurements.

You then have a choice of calibrating one against the other using a potentiometer (if the Arduino is more sensitive than the PC) or performing a software calibration / scaling.